# sql view from two tables

Tags: sql, view

I have a table of Neighborhood that has primary key - NID and a table of Apartment that has a foreign key  NeighborhoodID. 
How do I create a view that show in each neighborhood how much apartments there.
Thank you!

Comment: Which DBMS are you using ? Also provide sample input and desired output as text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd join the tables on the neighbourhood id, group by it, and count the rows:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW neighbourhood_apartments AS
SELECT   n.name, COUNT(*)
FROM     neighbourhood n
JOIN     apartment a ON n.nid = a.neightbourhoodid
GROUP BY n.name
```

Answer (score 0):

For each id in `neighborhood` count the rows in `apartment` that match the `neighborhoodid`:

```
   SELECT 
     neighborhood.id,
     neighborhood.name, 
     (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM apartment AS a WHERE a.neighborhoodid = n.id) AS counter  
   FROM
     neighborhood AS n
```